# Why is there an electrostatic field in a closed current?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-circuits, electricity, electric-fields

There is something about the derivation of the formula for parallel resistors I can not understand($1/R_t=1/R_1+\cdots+1/R_N$).

1. In order to derive this formula we use that the potential is the same no matter which road the current takes.
2. That the potential is the same follows from Coloumbs law from charges with an electrostatic field. By integrating the force from Coloumbs law we see that the force is conservative.
3. So before we derive the formula $1/R_t=1/R_1+\cdots+1/R_N$ we need to have established that the field is electrostatic?

What exactly is it that makes the field electrostatic? What is it for instance the prevents us from having current depending on time, and also a non-static field?

Comment: I have never seen an instance where the coulomb potential was used in this derivation, it would be best if you provided context to where you saw such a derivation.

Comment: @Triatticus I have not seen it directly but I assume it was used: It is said in various physics books that the potential difference across each resistor is the same because the field is conservative. The only explanation I have seen that the field is conservative is from the fact that electrostatic fields are conservative, and the fact that electrostatic fields are conservative follows from Coloumbs law.

Comment: It seems the Wikipedia article on kirchoffs laws, the actual root of your problem, might have some explanation. At least it has reasons why it might not be valid in certain circuits.

Comment: I also have not seen this derived based on Coulomb’s law. If there are currents then it is not electrostatic.

Comment: @Dale If the field is not electrostatic, then can you please provide the reason that the potential difference across each resistor is the same? How do we know that the field is conservative?

Comment: @user394334 , What is the source of this information ? Cause there exist non-conservative electric fields, responsible for closed currents. The derivation is not based on the potential. The constant potential covector field can only be assumed in ideal cases (that never exist in real life.) Moreover $\displaystyle \vec{J} = \sigma \vec{E}$. And charges are in motion thus field is not electrostatic i.e potential covector field is  not constant.

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi The source is myself and I have obviously misunderstood some facts. I have been trying to understand why the potential difference over two resistors in parallell are the same(this is what is used to derive $1/R_T=1/R_1+1/R_2$), and I thought it was because the electric field was conservative and hence the work on the carge is independent of the path the carge takes. So I thought I needed to explain why the field was conservative.

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi It says in my book when they derive the formula for reistence in parallell: "Remember that the potential difference between any two points does not depend on the path taken between the points.", University Physics, Fourtheenth Edition. I thought this was only possible if the field was conservative.

Comment: @Triatticus I think you are correct. In deriving Kirchoffs laws they use what is called a lumped element model, they assume that the change of magnetic flux is zero outside the elements, and hence from Faradays law they get that the field is conservative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the ends of the parallel resistors are joined at the ends so you have one common point -it does not matter if it is just one point or a wire without resistant-. So all points are at the same potential on one side, the same at the other side. This has nothing to do with conservative or electrostatic, they are also at every moment on the same potential if one has AC.

Comment: If we don't assume anything about conservative or electrostatic, how do we define potential? As I understand potential is defined relative to a point, but if we don't know that the field is conservative, the potential difference may depend on the reference point?, and the potential difference between A and B might also depend on which path one takes from A to B?

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter wich point you take for potential 0,  easiest would be at one end of your resistors. Than the Potential on the other side is defined by the work you need to transport a charge to this side divided by the magnitude of the charge. A wire or a conductor is supposed to not have a resistance, so the work along it ist 0. The potential on it ist the same at every point. This is the case with the wire which connects your transistors. For your parallel resistors only the voltage i.e. the potential difference matters, and of cause it changes, if you have AC, but in any moment you have a determined voltage. It makes no sense here to speak of a conservative field. To speak of a circuit and resistors in it, you have to have a source with a given potential difference. So what is really your problem?

Comment: The problem is regarding this statement: "Potential on the other side is defined by the work you need to transport a charge to this side divided by the magnitude of the charge." If the field is not conservative, this work may depend on the path?

Comment: i said "To speak of a circuit and resistors in it, you have to have a source with a given potential difference. Where should your not conservative field come from? Do you really think, you can transport a charge thru 2 different resistors  vom one end of a source to another with different work?  Or co you just play around with  words like conservative and not conservative fields?  Than you have to tell how you creat them an put resistors in it.

Comment: Yes, I think it is possible to transfer a charge through two different resistors and have different work. : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqjl-qRy71w But it seems that the answer to this question is that we assume that the time-varying magnetic field is zero outside a conductor(lumped element model), so Faradays law says that the field is conservative.

Comment: You startet with parallel resistors, now you talk about resistors in a loop?

Comment: The reason resistors in a loop is relevant is because the fact the the potential differene across parallell resistors is the same is equivalent to the fact that the sum of the potential difference over the corresponding loop is zero.